# What if wormholes were created when a black hole and white hole collide?

Tags: black-hole, wormhole, white-hole

Scientists have discovered black holes, white holes and wormholes but I am still unsure how they came to life. Did the black holes collide with the white hole causing a mixture of both or is there something else I need to know. I know that wormholes create a path where you can travel from one side of the universe to the other. I just want to know how they came about.

Comment: Hi welcome to AstroSE. We have confirmed the existence of black holes observationally. We have NOT confirmed the existence of white holes NOR worm holes observationally. This is very important to make clear. Also, a black hole can traverse a stable worm hole https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.09135 Also, these objects are not biological and thus are not considered to be alive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions that are purely hypothetical, such as about white holes or wormholes, are off-topic on this site. See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for further guidance. :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! If your question is closed as off-topic or a duplicate, you can then review the comments and links and see if you can edit your question and address those comments and it's possible that it can be reopened again. A question about "Black holes, white holes and wormholes" is too broad, and a quick check of Wikipedia will show that *scientists have not discovered the last two.*

Answer (score 3):

Black holes have been discovered.

White holes and wormholes have not been discovered, and probably don't exist.

Black holes can form from the collapse of dying stars.  If enough matter can be put in one place, without fusion to provide heat and pressure to prevent it, the matter will attract itself gravitationally, and become a black hole.

There is no known process that can create a white hole or wormhole. If they do exist, they would probably have to have always existed.  Wormholes in particular would be highly unstable, closing up if any matter passes in them.